# Replacing Panda int values with nan

Tags: pandas

Hi i currently have code

```
originalmsg['async'] = originalmsg.rename(index=fpsdata.set_index('index')['name']).index
originalmsg['async time'] = originalmsg.rename(index=fpsdata.set_index('index'['start_time']).index
originalmsg['async data'] = originalmsg.rename(index=fpsdata.set_index('index')['data']).index
```

and it produces a data frame that looks like this
[image]

I want the async, async time, and async data to be in the spot that they are located at but in the spots where there is no data, it gets filled up with an index number which I don't want. Is there a way to remove the numbers in-between while keeping the other information in the spots that they are located?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

for col in ['async', 'async time', 'async data']:
        originalmsg[col] = np.where(originalmsg[col].isin(originalmsg.index),
        np.nan, originalmsg[col])
```